# SQL to calculate average download in minutes

Tags: sql, impala

I'm having trouble to get the average **download in minutes** from the sample record as follows in ANSI-92 SQL or Impala SQL standard.

- *login_id   ,starttimestamp      ,stoptimestamp           ,download_bytes*
- abc@fcc.com, 2015-12-31 23:59:50, 2016-01-01 **00:00:20**, 438.0
- abc@fcc.com, 2016-01-01 **00:00:28**, 2016-01-01 **00:01:13**, 2190.0
- abc@fcc.com, 2016-01-01 **00:01:21**, 2016-01-01 00:01:54, 876.0
- abc@fcc.com, 2016-01-01 00:01:59, 2016-01-01 **00:02:34**, 1168.0
- abc@fcc.com, 2016-01-01 **00:02:43**, 2016-01-01 00:03:34, 1179.0

The time which is in bold share the time space ( in minutes group ) for starttimestamp and stoptimestamp. How to get the average download in

- 00:00:00 minutes *( 00:00:20 - 00:00:28 )*
- 00:01:00 minutes *( 00:01:13 - 00:01:21 )*
- 00:02:00 minutes *( 00:02:34 - 00:02:43 )*

and so on.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much in advance!

Regards,

Pozy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    (unix_timestamp(stoptimestamp)-unix_timestamp(starttimestamp)) / 60.0 diff_minutes
from your_table
```

using unix_timestamp() calculates the difference in seconds then divide by 60 or 60.0 depending on the precision you want in the result.

To calculate an average download over several rows you need to use SUM() to aggregate the bytes and alo sume the time unit. **You might want to use seconds for that inital calculation and then divide by 60.0**

The following example is written for SQL Sever as I don't have Impala to use

```
declare  @mytable table
    ([login_id] varchar(11), [starttimestamp_] datetime, [stoptimestamp_] datetime, [download_bytes] decimal(12,1))
;

INSERT INTO @mytable
    ([login_id], [starttimestamp_], [stoptimestamp_], [download_bytes])
VALUES
    ('abc@fcc.com', '2015-12-31 23:59:50', '2016-01-01 00:00:20', 438.0),
    ('abc@fcc.com', '2016-01-01 00:00:28', '2016-01-01 00:01:13', 2190.0),
    ('abc@fcc.com', '2016-01-01 00:01:21', '2016-01-01 00:01:54', 876.0),
    ('abc@fcc.com', '2016-01-01 00:01:59', '2016-01-01 00:02:34', 1168.0),
    ('abc@fcc.com', '2016-01-01 00:02:43', '2016-01-01 00:03:34', 1179.0)
;

select
  sum(download_bytes) sum_bytes
, sum(datediff(second,starttimestamp_,stoptimestamp_)) sum_time_unit
, sum(download_bytes)/sum(datediff(second,starttimestamp_,stoptimestamp_)) avg_bytes_sec
, (sum(download_bytes)/sum(datediff(second,starttimestamp_,stoptimestamp_)))/60.0 avg_bytes_min
from @mytable
-- WHERE ...
-- GROUP BY ...

+===========+===============+===============+===============+
| sum_bytes | sum_time_unit | avg_bytes_sec | avg_bytes_min |
+===========+===============+===============+===============+
| 5851      | 194           | 30.159793     | 0.502663      |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

see: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/576857/sql-to-calculate-average-download-in-minutes

Comment: how about the download_bytes ? do i need to average them ?

Comment: added more calculations to answer